# NaN value in R function

Tags: r

why is this R code line is generating NaN value even though the function inside the log is positive

```
Y[j]=Y[j]+y[i]*log(1/(exp(b[i])))+(1-y[i])*log(1-1/(exp(-b[i])))
```

Comment: care to share any data?

Comment: hey it would be great if you share some example data. From what I can guess, if b[i] is positive, exp(-b[i]) will be < 1, make 1-1/.. negative. Ultimately, we need to see the data input to understand why, agree?

Answer (score 0):

Because log(1-1/(exp(-b[i]))) is always 0. 1-1=0, so you have log(0/any possible number), then the fraction inside the log is 0 so the log(0) in r is always NaN.

Comment: Here a new code
Y[j]=Y[j]+y[i]*log(1/1+(exp(b[i])))+(1-y[i])*log(1-1/(1+(exp(-b[i]))))
but Y[j]=NaN

Comment: delete the last parte 1-1 in log(1-1/(1+(exp(-b[i])))) !!!!!!